# DNS second-level domain lookup

Tags: tcp, dns, web

How does DNS second-level domain lookup work?  For example, in a url web.example.com, the top-level domain is .com, and the second level domain is .example.  Based on my understanding, after we find a server for the top-level domain, if this top-level server does not actually have a record for the second-level domain, we query a different top-level server.  How does DNS decide which next top-level domain server to query?  Are there a lot of top-level domain servers in the world (since there are so many second-level names available)?  Since there are so many second-level names, how long could this process potentially take?

This is described on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Address_resolution_mechanism, but this section does not explain how to efficiently find the top-level server with the second-level domain info.

The point of my question is how does DNS efficiently search millions/billions of second-level domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS second- (and third-, and fourth-) level domain lookup works exactly the same way first-level domain lookup works.

The description you present in the question is wrong. For example, "if this top-level server does not actually have a record for the second-level domain, we query a different top-level server" is wrong. If one of the servers for a domain does not have a record for a subdomain one level down, that's the end of the search: the subdomain does not exist.

A full description of how DNS resolution works is outside the scope of a SO answer, but in a nutshell:

Starting from the root servers, each DNS server either gives an answer to the question or a referral to another server. Assuming a query for `web.example.com`, the root servers will give you a referral to the gTLD servers for `com.`. You will then go query one of those servers. It will give you a referral to the nameservers for `example.com`. You will now go query one of those servers. It will probably give you an answer (either an error like `NXDOMAIN` (no such domain) or some records). It could also give you a referral if the subdomain `web.example.com` has been further delegated to some other servers...

Comment: 1) "the root servers will give you a referral to the gTLD servers for com..  You will then go query one of those servers."  --  If you query one of the gTLD servers for .com, how are you sure it will know a nameserver for example.com?  If it does not know, does it query a different gTLD server?  2) "It will give you a referral to the nameservers for example.com."  -- The way it is used in this sentence, is a nameserver one of the servers that has a record of the ip address for example.com?

Comment: 1) It's the **job** of the gTLD servers for "com." to know how to know the nameserver for "example.com.". It has been configured with a database that contains this information. That's what it means to be an authoritative nameserver for "com.". It will not in turn query a different gTLD server to get the information. 2) in that sentence, nameserver for example.com. means "authoritative nameserver for example.com.", meaning one of the nameservers that has been provisioned with all of the resource records contained in the "example.com." zone, including probably "web.example.com."

Comment: This is hard to believe. That one gTLD can know the nameserver for all each possible second-level domain (such as "example.com") since there could be so many possible second-level domains. Do you have a reference for this?  Based on wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Structure) each label is up to 63 characters, so if we limit to the english alphabet, this already gives us 26^63 possible second-level domains.  How would a server store this much data?  Or is there an error in my approximation?

Comment: Well, the "com." zone is indeed a big damn zone. It's got millions of entries. And, yes, all 13 of the gTLD servers that serve this zone (actually way more than 13 servers due to server clusters and anycast) have to locally know the delegation referrals for each of the millions of records it contains. Still, "com." contains a lot fewer records than the theoretically possible maximum of more than 26^63. Clearly, it's manageable, since it works. For a reference, try the original DNS RFCs, 1034 and 1035.

Comment: Hence the reason why it's more than 13 servers: it's frelling huge.  But like how Google can process millions of searches a second, the gTLD guys can just throw more servers at the problem to keep up with capacity.